# Check number of log invocations

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, log4j

I have written the following UT and I can't understand why it fails all the time:

```
        final Appender mockAppender = mock(Appender.class);
        MyClass.log.addAppender(mockAppender);
        final ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);
        Log4jConfigHelper.getInstance().bufferConfiguration();

        MyClass.log.warn("adasd");

        final List<LoggingEvent> allValues = captor.getAllValues();
        verify(mockAppender).doAppend(captor.capture());
        assertThat(allValues.get(0).getMessage().toString(), equalTo("adasd"));
```

Failure trace:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
appender.doAppend(<Capturing argument>);
-> at com.bet.blues.be.processor.IORequestProcessorTest_rejectSend.rejectSend_orderNotRejected_overrideRejectUser(IORequestProcessorTest_rejectSend.java:123)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
-> at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.removeAllAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:141)
```

Can you explain me where the problem may be?

Comment: can u please give the error log

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks!